# ROracle interrupt long-running queries

Tags: r, oracle

I'm executing SQL statements from R interface by using ROracle package. But sometimes it takes a lot of time and i want to interrupt it.

I find a function `"oracle()"` in ROracle package and this function has a parameter `"interruptible = FALSE"` . It seems that i can interrupt it using this set.

And in this function help document , it says :

> When interruptible is set to TRUE, it allows for interrupting long-running
>   queries on the server by executing the query in a thread. Main thread checks 
>   for Ctrl-C and issues OCIBreak/OCIReset to cancel the operation on the server.
>   By default interruptible is FALSE.

But i try ctrl-c, it doesn't work. So anyone can help? thanks!!

```
sessionInfo: R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-
mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
      [2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936    [3] 
    LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                             
    [5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
```